# force customers to add only single item to card per purchase EDD

Tags: plugins, php, customization

Is there any way to force Easy Digital Downloads customers to add only single item to card per purchase?
In other words, disable shopping card "completely", So that when a customer touches the download button of an item, if he returns to the download archive page, it will be deleted from his shopping cart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched a lot and find a way to do it.

add following to theme functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'edd_pre_add_to_cart_contents', '__return_false' );
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/amdrew/2192eb02839fcdf9e3d2

Thanks!